# CKEditor widget - Use variable inside template

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I've got a custom CKEditor widget, and inside the template I've got a variable that inserts text that differs each time the widget is inserted.

```
    template:
        '<div>' +
            changingText +
        '</div>'
```

The first time it is inserted, it does use the correct *changingText* values. However, since the template is only initialized once the value that it inserts is always the value it was set to on init. Is there a way to potentially re-init the template so it's updated, or any other way that it could use the updated *changingText* value each time it's inserted?

Comment: Can you post more code, just enough so we can reproduce the issue, try to fix it and give you an answer?

Comment: @blex This is pretty much the only relevant code for it. With CKEditor, if you make a custom widget and set that as the template you'll get what I have. If you insert the template, then you'll get whatever text changingText is set to, but if you change changingText it'll still be the initial value because it isn't ever re-running the template code.